# Add a button (or any element) after the last recyclerview element Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Basically, I need to add a button after the last element in the recyclerview. That's because the user can push this button to load more content from the server.

I using cards por show the information in the recycler view, and I trying to inflate a special card, with the button that I need, but I don't know how inflate this card after to inflate the last card using the cursor data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to override `getItemViewType(int position)` in your adapter.

`public final int CONTENT_TYPE = 1;
public final int BUTTON_TYPE = 2;`

Lets say your cursor count is 'x'. For positions 0 to (x-1), you will inflate the cardview with the cursor content. Hence, `getItemViewType` will return CONTENT_TYPE for positions 0 to (x-1). Next, for position 'x', return BUTTON_TYPE.

You will get hold of the view type in the `onCreateXXX` method  of your adapter. Based on the view type, inflate the right xml (button or cursor content).

Be sure to return cursor count + 1 in the getItemCount() method. (+1 being for the button layout).

Answer (score 1):

Build a Load More Button into a recyclerview.

The first thing to do is to create a layout with your button and modify your viewhold to get the button id:

Then a simple way to make a button is to add +1 to the getItemCount() and a flag (i.e. boolean) to know if you need to draw the button.

The new getItemCount with the flag will look like this:

```
private boolean hasLoadButton = true;

public boolean isHasLoadButton() {
return hasLoadButton;
}

public void setHasLoadButton(boolean hasLoadButton) {
this.hasLoadButton = hasLoadButton;
notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
if (hasLoadButton) {
    return data.size() + 1;
} else {
    return data.size();
}
}
```

Then you have to override into the adapter the method to get the type of the view:

```
private final int TITLE = 0;
private final int LOAD_MORE = 1;
@Override                                 
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
if (position < getItemCount()) {     
    return TITLE;                         
} else {                              
    return LOAD_MORE;                         
}                                     
}
```

If the position is between 0 and data.size()-1, you will have a typeView for the title, else a typeview for the load more button.

Now we have to create the view holder:

In the method onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType), y

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) 
{

    if(viewType == TITLE) {

        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.nav_draw_row, parent, false));

    } else if (view type == LOAD_MORE) {

        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.load_more_row, parent, false));

    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

load_more_row

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/load_more"
    android:text="load more !"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Don't forget to change your viewholder to include the new button.

And finally the method onBindViewHolder :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

if(position >= getItemCount) {

    holder.loadMore....
} else {
NavDrawerItem current = data.get(position);
holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
}

}
```